# ibrowser and tinymce: nothing happens when ibrowser icon is clicked

Tags: php, tinymce

I have installed ibrowser plugin. Do every thing in [here](http://pascal.vanhecke.info/2005/08/25/image-upload-plugin-for-tinymce/) and [here](http://www.eliotdill.com/2008/09/ibrowser-free-image-upload-for-tiny-mce-and-other-editors/)

Addin javascript as below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

tinyMCE.init({

theme : "advanced",
mode : "textareas",
plugins : "ibrowser",
theme_advanced_buttons3_add : "ibrowser"

});

function toggleEditor(id) {
  if (!tinyMCE.get(id))
  tinyMCE.execCommand("mceAddControl", false, id);
  else
  tinyMCE.execCommand("mceRemoveControl", false, id);
}
</script>
```

but nothing happens when ibrowser icon is clicked.(already with "var ib = null;" )
Any idea for solving the problem? 
Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you got firebug? Install it on Firefox and see if you get any errors in the console.

Comment: ib is null: ib.isMSIE = tinymce.isIE;

Comment: @jasmine: I was able to fix the "ib is null" problem, but thats the tip of the iceberg. See my answer to alternatives to iBrowse.

Comment: @jasmine: Did you had any luck?

Comment: After fixing some errors, it works only on IE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hi jasmine.**

I have used TinyMCE for nearly two years, and i use its own plugins for handling files and images ([MCFileManager](http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/plugins_filemanager.php) / [MCImageManager](http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/plugins_imagemanager.php)).

I did some testing with iBrowser, and some versions work with Firefox 2 and older but not Firefox 3, others don't work with Internet Explorer or Safari. So from this i can say that iBrowser has big Javascript cross-browser issues, so i don't recommend using it at all, until the developer as release a new version that works with all major browsers.

My suggestion is to use [MCFileManager](http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/plugins_filemanager.php) or [MCImageManager](http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/plugins_imagemanager.php) both developed by the same team that developed TinyMCE, unfortunately they come at a price.

But probably you don't want to pay a license to use neither of them, so try using **[TinyMCE Ajax File Manager](http://www.phpletter.com/Demo/Tinymce-Ajax-File-Manager/)**, has loots of features like the original plugins for TinyMCE.

*To see a demo working go [here](http://demo.phpletter.com/tinymce_test.php) and try inserting a image, you will see a button [alt text http://demo.phpletter.com/tiny_mce/themes/advanced/images/browse.gif](http://demo.phpletter.com/tiny_mce/themes/advanced/images/browse.gif) right next to the Image Url textfield*

Some of the features of [TinyMCE Ajax File Manager](http://www.phpletter.com/Demo/Tinymce-Ajax-File-Manager/):

- Multiple Javascript Editors supported, such as Tinymce and FCKeditor.
- Fully employ AJAX & PHP to function file management.
- Faster to load and avoid reloading the whole window.
- A Build-In Advanced Image Editor
- Multi-language supported (utf-8)
- Access control supported
- Fully customizable, create your own theme
- Text Editable
- Media Previewable (Movies, Musics)

Try it.. See if it fits your needs.

Good luck.